# Math PhoneGap Plugin?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math, cordova

Does anyone know if there is a mathematics PhoneGap plugin that will provide you with Javascript and/or Objective-C (I'm working on an iOS app.) math functions?  I found a list of iPhone PhoneGap plugins (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone), but a math one was not listed.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

EDIT: Here are some *Javascript* PhoneGap libraries, but even then, no math :( ... http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501579/JavaScript%20Libraries

Comment: What kind of math functions are you looking for?

Comment: @MobileOverlord Anything, really.  I was just wondering if there was a phonegap math library out there that I could mess with.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a build in math library for performing routine math functions. You can use this Math object and then pass the results back and forth between a PhoneGap plugin and back.

[Javascript Math Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_math.asp)

It would be pretty cool to bridge some expensive math functions off to native code. If you are looking to do basic math, javascript will handle this probably faster than bridging it to Objective-C since you're going to take a performance reduction in the code execution required to bridge to the plugin. Check out the Phone Gap articles on creating iOS plugins.

[PhoneGap Creating iOS Plugins](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I'm to avoid this as it is a big hassle to send variables from Javascript to Objective-C and then  back again.

Comment: So are you writing primarily in ObjC? If you have a PhoneGap Project you are probably going to spend a majority of your time in javascript.

Comment: Most of my code is indeed in Javascript, but I was hoping to experiment with an Objective-C math library where I'd like to do some "heavy lifting."

Comment: I added some information on making a phonegap plugin. You may want to save this for very expensive math routines like matrix or linear equations due to the performance reduction from bridging to the plugin. Simple math is probably going to execute faster in JS.